# Partitioning elements in list by \t . Python

Tags: python, list, append, partitioning, sublist

```
my_list = ['1\tMelkor\tMorgoth\tSauronAtDolGoldul','2\tThingols\tHeirIsDior\tSilmaril','3\tArkenstone\tIsProbablyA\tSilmaril']
```

I'm trying to split this list into sublists separated by \t

```
output = [['1','Melkor','Morgoth','SauronAtDolGoldul'],['2','Thigols','HeirIsDior','Silmaril'],['3','Arkenstone','IsProbablyA','Silmaril']]
```

I was thinking something on the lines of

```
output = []
for k_string in my_list:
    temp = []
    for i in k_string:
        temp_s = ''
        if i != '\':
            temp_s = temp_s + i
        elif i == '\':
            break
        temp.append(temp_s)
```

it gets messed up with the t . . i'm not sure how else I would go about doing it.  I've seen people use .join for similar things but I don't really understand how to use .join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split); a list comprehension lets you apply this to all elements in one line:

```
output = [sub.split('\t') for sub in my_list]
```

There is no literal `\` in the string; the `\t` is an escape code that signifies the tab character.

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = ['1\tMelkor\tMorgoth\tSauronAtDolGoldul','2\tThingols\tHeirIsDior\tSilmaril','3\tArkenstone\tIsProbablyA\tSilmaril']
>>> [sub.split('\t') for sub in my_list]
[['1', 'Melkor', 'Morgoth', 'SauronAtDolGoldul'], ['2', 'Thingols', 'HeirIsDior', 'Silmaril'], ['3', 'Arkenstone', 'IsProbablyA', 'Silmaril']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import csv
>>> my_list = ['1\tMelkor\tMorgoth\tSauronAtDolGoldul','2\tThingols\tHeirIsDior\tSilmaril','3\tArkenstone\tIsProbablyA\tSilmaril']
>>> list(csv.reader(my_list, delimiter='\t'))
[['1', 'Melkor', 'Morgoth', 'SauronAtDolGoldul'], ['2', 'Thingols', 'HeirIsDior', 'Silmaril'], ['3', 'Arkenstone', 'IsProbablyA', 'Silmaril']]
```